# Strip prefix from variable - bash

Tags: bash, prefix, strip

Adding a shell script (/bin/bash) to an automator workflow (copy file path) I want to use this to strip the constant prefix '/Volumes/' from the variable path which is being copied to the clipboard.

EG The copy file path workflow copies '/Volumes/GRAID/audiovideo.mov' to the clipboard, the path I desire to paste is 'GRAID/audiovideo.mov'

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To remove a known constant prefix `/Volumes/` from a shell variable named `foo`, you can write:

```
foo="${foo#/Volumes/}"
```

(See [the *Bash Reference Manual*, §3.5.3 "Shell Parameter Expansion"](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion).)